# How to keep the Firebase Auth instance between pages

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am working on a project where i need to login a teacher with their email and password. Or create a teacher profile with their name, email, and password, then send in to firebase database using firebaseUser.uid. After authenticating them, I send them to their teacher page.

```
function init(){
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    $('#submit').on('click', Login);
    $('#signUp').on('click', signup)
    $('#create').on('click', sendInfo);
}

function Login(){
    var email = $('#emailI').val();
    var pass = $('#passI').val(); 

    var promise = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser =>{
        if(firebaseUser){
            console.log(firebaseUser);
            setTimeout(replace, 2500);
        }else{
            console.log("not logged in");
        }
    });
}
```

Code Continued...

```
function sendInfo(){
        //Get information values
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var pass = $('#pass').val();
        var name = $('#name').val();

        //Create user with createUserWithEmailAndPassowrd();
        var promise = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

        stateChanged(email,pass,name);
    }

function stateChanged(email,pass,name){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser =>{
        if(firebaseUser){
            console.log(firebaseUser);
            //Create Firebase database ref
            var ref = firebase.database().ref('Teachers');
            ref.child(firebaseUser.uid).set({
                Name:name,
                Email:email,
                Passowrd:pass,
            });
            setTimeout(replace, 2500);
        }else{
            console.log("Not Logged In");
        }

    });
}

function replace(name){
    location.replace("teacherPage.html?room=" + name);
}
```

The next portion of the project is creating an h1 at the top of the specific teacher page with their name pulled from firebase

```
//Pull teacher name form Firebase 
    var pullName = firebase.database().ref("Teachers").child(firebaseUser.uid);
    pullName.once('value', function(snapshot){
        data = snapshot.val();
        name = data.Name;
        console.log(name);

     var teachName = document.createElement("h1");
        teachName.textContent = name;
        teachName.className = "tName";

        document.getElementById("firstHead").appendChild(teachName);
    });
```

These are just the main parts I am having trouble with. A lot of this project depends on the Auth Instance working on each page. I save all specific teacher information under firebaseUser.uid. However, the console in google chrome says firebaseUser is undefined. How do I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: When you call location.replace(...) a new webpage is loaded and your JS instance variables are cleared (there are no variables set in the new page). If you can create a single page application your JS variables would remain, or you can save them in cookie, local storage, send as parameter, ...

Comment: It's a bit hard to see what code is on what page. But you'll need a `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` handler on each page. Firebase automatically detects whether there is already a signed in user and calls the `onAuthStateChanged` handler with that state.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I needed, a firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged for each